# Mechanism for a mechanical latch/clamp

Tags: mechanical-engineering

A wooden police baton has to be hung on the back of an officer and released only when s/he wants it to be released. I thought about "push to stow, push to release". This is a thought experiment, I am not a manufacturer...

The baton is smooth without grooves so alternative solution of releasing by rotation (like BNC plugs, or push/push pen) won't work.

Where can I find a simple design of such contraption or what terms would I use to describe this?

---

This is a rough model of a four bar (ABCFD) which push point E toward the object to hold (LMNOQ)

The object, represent here as rectangle LMNOQ, moves on a fixed bar (HL).
When pushed up (represented by piston A1 expanding), point E moves towards the edge NQ. The angle FDB (in the locked position) is > 180 , so it should be locked, as with locking pliers.

In the open position, LMNOQ is lower, and point E is far from it.
(this model is only for showing the idea. I am sure it should be modified to work in the real world)

**HOW can a SECOND push unlock point D?**

[[image: partial clamping mechanism]]
[[image: baton is held]
[image: baton released]

Comment: Open up a "clicky-top" ballpoint pen for one standard example.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do here; what does "hang this stick vertically" mean? How does it constitute a "mechanical latch" per the title? Please [edit] your question to clearly describe the application. A diagram wouldn't hurt.

Comment: is the stick going to support a load or just the stick itself? Can just the end of the stick have some type of engagement features?

Comment: the stick (baton) has to carry its own weight. It has to be smooth, so no grooves or other engagement features

Comment: how about you replace the "magic" with a spring and the two clamping trapezoids with urethane wheels. Put the Urethane wheels on some type of a friction inducing bearing. Now you can freely insert and remove the baton as needed as long as the friction of the wheels is correct, they won't slide out.

Comment: I understand how the wheels will resist pulling, but how do you release them? ( i.e. disengaging the wheels from the baton). Pushing against the spring will only tighten the hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanism you're looking for is named **push-push latch**. They are used in a lot of places and there are various patents for that. You can check [this patent](https://www.google.com/patents/EP1596030A2?cl=un) granted at 2005. It is for a small holder but it can be modified for bigger projects. 
[image: Figure from Patent EP1596030 A2]

However if I were you I'd desing a plastic holder such as the stress holder at [Kinetxbatons](http://kinetxbatons.com/product/) picture given below. Moving parts and mechanisms are prone to errors and dirt is a real problem. You can check snap-fit design books I've linked in another [answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/snap-fit-design/3341#3341).

[image: Kinetxbatons stress holder]

Comment: very nice! The patent is from 2005 which is pretty amazing for me. I would expect such machines to be invented in the end of 19th century when everything was done mechanically.
As for "less moving parts is better" - totally agree.

Comment: Patent date isn't an indication of uniqueness of solution. There might be a lot patents that resemble and solve the problem but you'll find a new aspect and get that patented. So I'm sure there were prior art.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information given in your question, it sounds like you might want a mechanism similar in operating principal to what is called a "push to open" drawer slide. On these drawers the draw doesn't open when you pull on it, you have to push it past a detent point and then it opens by itself basically. Hope this helps !

Comment: This would be greatly improved if you were to add a diagram.  As it stands it's practically a copy of the question.

Comment: Hi Carl, if I had one I would post it, order one of the slides from Grizzly, John Dewey called it learn by doing ;-)